# Making multiselect work with simpleform, in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, simple-form

My aim is to have a teacher be able to select multiple curriculums they are able to teach, I am using simple-forms. It could be checkbox or tags

Below is my setup.

TeacherProfile model

```
class TeacherProfile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subject 
  belongs_to :grade
  # belongs_to :curriculum
  has_many :curriculums
  belongs_to :user

  validates :national_identity, :curriculum_ids, :grade_id, :subject_id,
    :employer, :years_teaching, 
    :about_me, presence: true

  def self.teachers_classes(user_id)
    ClassRoom.where(user_id: user_id)
  end
end
```

Curriculum model

```
class Curriculum < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :student_profiles
  has_many :teacher_profiles
end
```

Form

```
.py-5.bg-light-v2
  .container
    .row.align-items-center
        .col-md-6
            %h2 Teacher Profile

%section.padding-y-50.border-bottom.border-light
  .container
    .row
      .col.col-md-8.mb-5
        = simple_form_for(@teacher_profile) do |f|
          = f.error_notification
          = f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present?

          .border-bottom.mb-4.pb-4
            %h5.mb-4 
              Personal Details
              %br
              %small.text-muted select what applies to you, tick if it applies to you.

            = f.input :national_identity, label: "Enter your National ID or Passort", placeholder:"216331771"
            = f.input :special_education, label: "I have Special education skills"
            = f.input :has_hardware, label: "I have a computer & Internet"
            = f.input :is_available, label: "I am available to tutor"
            = f.input :has_tsc_certificate, label: "I have a TSC certificate"
            = f.input :has_good_conduct, label: "I have  good conduct certificate"

          .border-bottom.mb-4.pb-4
            %h5.mb-4 Professional Details
            = f.input :years_teaching, label: "I have been teaching since"
            .row
              -# .col= f.association :curriculum, prompt: "Select the curriculum you use"
              .col= f.association :curriculums, input_html: {:multiple => true} 
              .col= f.association :grade, prompt: "Select the grades you teach"
            = f.association :subject, prompt: "Select the subjects you teach"
            = f.input :employer, label: "I currently work at", placeholder:"Enter name of employer if applicable or leave blank"

          .border-bottom.mb-4.pb-4
            %h5.mb-4 About your passion
            = f.input :about_me, as: :text, label: "Tell us why you love teaching", placeholder:"I am passionate about teaching..."

          .form-actions
            = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg mt-2"
```

I am getting an error:

```
Curriculum ids can't be blank
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: Please read "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need to be able to run the code to generate the error.

Comment: Both your models have `has_many` associations. To get it working you need to use `has_and_belongs_to_many` instead

Comment: thank you @theTinMan i didn't even know that exists. learned a lot.

Comment: @Vasilisa I went with a joining table, works like a charm. Will look into using has_and_belongs_to_many as well. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a joining table with a many-to-many relationship. This separates the problem, allows adding the extra fields without too much work.

Create migration table/model X, and reference the desired fields, in this case use `subjects`, `curriculum`, `grades` and `teacher_profiles`.

Create a many-to-many relationship in this table, then make the new model nested under `teacher_profiles`.

The video "[Rails - Nested Forms in Rails | [Tutorial]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niLRlaL-ss0)" is useful.

Comment: Please, add more important part of code to the answer.

Comment: Your answer is a start, but, as @Vasilisa said, summarize the changes and explain why they helped. A description of the changes you made isn't nearly as useful as the code. Also, remember, answers are to be concise and clear. I removed a lot of chatty "fluff" as it's not really desirable on SO. Remember, SO is like a reference book; We're a little less formal, but we want clear and concise information.

Answer (score 0):

In the model you should validate `curriculums`, not `curriculum_ids`.